# How should i approach dynamic page creation with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project which includes dynamic custom page creation. Instead of beginning from zero, i thought it would be quicker to use my one of the old codes. It has a folder called "pages", it includes custom page codes with ".inc" extension which generated from a code in admin panel.

I check the file in mysql, if it exists in 'pages' table before running the script inside it for security reasons.

this is the code running the check.

```
function page_control($page)
{
    global $db;
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = ? AND active = ? LIMIT  1 ', array($page, "1"));
    if ($db->returned_rows > 0)
        return TRUE;
}
```

Each page generated have no similar structure so i couldn't find which just allows user to enter content and nothing else. Except i thought just adding some premade templates and mark them as like "empty blog template", "empty gallery template" etc. and let user choose the template before generating the dynamic page.

Is this a good approach or i would like to know if there is a different way to make this possible.

Comment: In what way is what you are describing different from installing wordpress or similar blogging software?

Comment: Its a private software.